# Count rows between two cells datagridview using linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, datagridview

I have a datagridview (vb.net, winforms) in which I read data from excel sheet,
Now, If a row is having value "Code" and another row having same value in same column then

[image: Image Shows two cells with "Code" value]

How I can  count rows between these two cells using linq or any other method.?

Comment: @TimSchmelter using a datatable..

Answer (score 0):

This will count the rows between two occurrences of a particular value:

```
Private Sub DGVSearchTestButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DGVSearchTestButton.Click
    Try
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("CodeValue"))

        addRow(dt, "100")
        addRow(dt, "200")
        addRow(dt, "300")
        addRow(dt, "400")
        addRow(dt, "100")
        addRow(dt, "200")
        addRow(dt, "300")

        dgvSearch.DataSource = dt

        Debug.Print(countRowsBetween(0, "200"))

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message))
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub addRow(dt As DataTable, rowValue As String)
    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow
    dr.Item("CodeValue") = rowValue
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
End Sub

Private Function countRowsBetween(columnNumber As Integer, valueToSearchFor As String) As Integer
    Dim rowCount As Integer = -1

    Dim findFirst As Boolean
    Dim findSecond As Boolean
    Dim searchFromRow As Integer

    For rowParse As Integer = 0 To dgvSearch.RowCount
        If dgvSearch.Rows(rowParse).Cells(columnNumber).Value.ToString = valueToSearchFor Then
            findFirst = True
            searchFromRow = rowParse + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If findFirst Then
        For rowParse As Integer = searchFromRow To dgvSearch.RowCount
            If dgvSearch.Rows(rowParse).Cells(columnNumber).Value.ToString = valueToSearchFor Then
                findSecond = True
                rowCount = rowParse - searchFromRow
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Return rowCount

End Function
```